# Controlling the number of links shown in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to show links of favourite posts in the sidebar but I want to controll the number of links to show only 3 links and if this is exceeded, i want the link to View All favourites to show.

PHP:

```
<?php
$favorites = va_get_dashboard_favorites($dashboard_user->ID, (bool) $is_own_dashboard );

if ( $favorites->post_count > 0 ) {
while ( $favorites->have_posts() ) : $favorites->the_post();

$post_status = $is_own_dashboard ? 'post-status' : '';
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $post_status ); ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($ID); ?>">My link to a post or page</a><?php echo    get_the_title($ID); ?>
</article>
<?php
endwhile;
} else {
?>

<?php
}
 }
```

How can I achieve this?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the va_get_dashboard_favorites function elsewhere which looks to be the same. The easiest way would be to limit the va_get_dashboard_favorites() WP_Query. e.g.

**METHOD 1**

**This code was found in wp-content/themes/vantage-new/includes/dashboard.php by the way**:

```
function va_get_dashboard_favorites( $user_id, $self = false ) {

    $favorites = new WP_Query( array(
      'connected_type'  => 'va_favorites',
      'connected_items' => $user_id,
      'nopaging'        => true,
      'posts_per_page' => 3, // limiting posts to 3
    ) );

    return $favorites;

}
```

Then to add a view-all link, just add it in iunder the while loop. e.g.

```
<?php
    $favorites = va_get_dashboard_favorites($dashboard_user->ID, (bool) $is_own_dashboard );

    if ( $favorites->post_count > 0 ) {
        while ( $favorites->have_posts() ) : $favorites->the_post();

        $post_status = $is_own_dashboard ? 'post-status' : '';
?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $post_status ); ?>>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content-listing', get_post_status() ); ?>
    </article>
<?php
        endwhile;
?>
    <br /><a href="#yourview-all-link-here">View all</a>
<?php
    } else {
?>
```

---

**METHOD 2 (Updated as per OP's update)**

As per OP's comments, the updated code to just show 3 links

```
<?php
    $favorites = va_get_dashboard_favorites($dashboard_user->ID, (bool) $is_own_dashboard );

    $counter = 0;
    $max = 3;
    if ( $favorites->post_count > 0 ) {
        while ( $favorites->have_posts() and ($counter < $max)) : $favorites->the_post();

            $post_status = $is_own_dashboard ? 'post-status' : '';
?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $post_status ); ?>>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content-listing', get_post_status() ); ?>
    </article>
<?php
            $counter++;
        endwhile;
?>
    <br /><a href="#yourview-all-link-here">View all</a>
<?php
    } else {
?>
```

Comment: i have changed the code abit. I dont want to limit the number of posts but just number of links displayed

Comment: Thanks..but the code you have provide limits the post and not the number of links that are displayed with `<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></a></li>`

Comment: You need to post the code for the template_part 'content-listing' then as this is apparently where it's being listed out.

Comment: The template_part "content-listing' is being used in another part of the website and changing that will cause the appearance to change.. I thought controlling the number of links displayed would be relatively simple

Comment: The looping of the links themselves from what you've said is inside the template part content-listing.. so if we are unable to modify that then there's no way to easily limit the links. I suggest copying the content-listing partial so we can modify it and use it just for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry.. I just looked at my code again and i had copied the wrong code. I have changed the code above and it does NOT include the content-listing part..sorry for the inconvenience. From here i thinkg controlling the links should be simple?

Comment: as you suggested, I copied and changed part of the template_part "content listing" and used that code above (in your advised method 2 and it worked). Thanks alot. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that WP_Query would work in this situation.

```
<?php $posts = WP_Query(array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3
    //any other options can go in this array
)); ?>
// Your code goes here
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?> //This makes sure your query doesn't affect other areas of the page
<a href="linktomorefavorites/">View More</a>
```

Comment: thanks but adding this code give me Call to undefined function WP_Query() error